# Issues with PWA in standalone mode on iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, safari, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps

My web app works just fine in every browser I can find. If I install the app on my desktop in Firefox and Chrome, it works just fine online and offline just fine. Same with desktop Safari.

My issue is with Safari on mobile. If I use the browser, everything seems to work online or offline, no issue. But, when I add the app to my homescreen, open the app at least once in standalone mode (to kick off the caching), and then shut off my network connection. Problem is, when I try and start using the app again, I get the dreaded "No connection" screen inside of my app.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this doesn't work and I'm about ready to toss my computer out the window.

I am currently using the `InjectManifest` method in the `workbox-webpack-plugin` in order to put workbox and my precache manifest into my service worker.

My manifest:

```
{
  "short_name": "React Notes",
  "name": "React PWA notes",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "staticAssets/favicon.png",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "staticAssets/icon-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "staticAssets/icon-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "scope":"/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

My service-worker:

```
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);

workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

The head on my index.html

```
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
...
<!-- here be apple specific icon stuff -->
```

My workbox webpack plugin config

```
new workboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
  swSrc: './src/sw.js',
  swDest: 'service-worker.js',
  importWorkboxFrom: 'local'
})
```

I'm half expecting it has something to do with the  of my index.html, or the manifest, BUT nothing I change works.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Try posting in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/your-first-pwapp/issues). This might help them check if there are issue for a specific version on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be due to the fact that workbox uses importScripts and currently iOS does not cache imported scripts correctly. It's an upcoming fix.

Try and reference all the workbox files directly and then comment out the import scripts line in the main workbox JavaScript.

Comment: This was the issue actually, luckily I've been informed we don't have to worry about iOS. But yah, it's a webkit bug

Comment: May I ask how can I reference the the workbox files directly?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this answers your question, but I had a similar problem lately, maybe it was the same:

Everything worked fine in browsers, desktop and mobile, but when installed to the homescreen on mobile, the app didnt start, as you described.

I used workbox for offline functionality and had a starting url that was not caught by the regex for caching routes. After adding this route, the offline mode for installed apps on mobile worked... I still dont know why it worked in browser.